# Robot Framework - customize the message in Report.html

Tags: report, robotframework, assert

When the robot framework test suite is executed, report.html is created. In the report, there is a message column that is populated only when my assert statement fails. What if I want to give a message even when my assert passes? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Set test message](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message) keyword from the BuiltIn library